# Signup page always redirecting to login page even if there are errors during signup

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a signup page for users. It is working fine except the process when there are errors in the form introduced. After hitting the `signup` button, the page redirects to `login` with a notification saying `username or password mismatch`. This is the notification introduced by me into `login` page if there are any errors.

inside `views.py`

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form =SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            error=form.errors
            return render(request,'registration/signup.html',{'error':error})

            #return redirect('signup',{'error':error})
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
        return render(request,'registration/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

my template for `signup.html` is:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <h1>Error {{error}}</h1>
        {{ error }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

`path('signup/',views.signup,name='signup')`
`path('accounts/login/',LoginView.as_view(), name='login')`

form for signup is:

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name=forms.CharField(label="First Name",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
    last_name=forms.CharField(label='Last Name')

    #Removes the help_texts
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].help_text = None


    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('first_name','last_name','username','email','password1','password2')
```

Why does this happen? How can I render the same signup page to user with extra information of showing errors . like `**some_error** happened. Please fill out the form again`. And why is this page redirecting to login page for every case and why is this showing errors on login page when it is supposed to show errors in the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form =SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')


    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request,'registration/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

Just make it like a final `return(return(your main template))`. It'll just load the form every time no matter what.
**NOTE**- Remove the `action="{% url%}`. This is the reason why you are just going to the `login` page everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `{{ error }}` into a for loop, like this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
  {% for error in form.errors %}
    <h1>Error {{error}}</h1>
    {{ error }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Here is the [relevant section from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages)

Comment: But why is it redirecting this page to login page and out of all the things, why is it showing errors there?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain on why, but I believe it has to do with the construction of the def foo (request): function. It always needs something to return in that place. (Sorry, I'm self taught so I don't no the technical specific!)

Answer (score 0):

The last render return has to be in line with the if statement; yours is tabbed too far over. Do it like this:

```
def signup(request):
        form = SignupForm()
        if request.method=='POST':
            form =SignupForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                error=form.errors
                return render(request,'registration/signup.html',{'error':error})

        return render(request,'registration/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: I have ```else``` for the first if statement. ```if request.method is not POST``` then **return** and render the original form page.. Is it not a logical thing?